# MySQL connection timeout, inactivity

Tags: mysql, timeout, python-idle

I have MySQL server installed and I would like it to stop dropping inactive connections. Which option do I need to adjust?  The MySQL server is installed on a Windows machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the MySQL [wait_timeout variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=2147483
```