# Constant re-connection to database causes program to be slow

Tags: c++, database, qt, connection

So I've heard that it's good programming when you close your database connection as soon as you don't need that connection and just re-open it when you do. So, I've been closing my connection whenever I don't need it, however I've noticed that it's slowed down my program significantly (it takes ~2 seconds per window to open). Any way to solve this?

I've defined `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");` as a global, and just did `db.open();` or `db.close();` whenever I needed. In addition, if I just keep my connection open the whole time, my windows load instantly.

Edit: Reason why people say this is because connections could get dropped/disconnected midway through using your program and it could lead to unsaved data/big problems etc

Comment: Best to keep connections open.

Comment: May be you should use `transaction()` and `commit()` to avoid data damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, leave the db connection open.  If you're worried about a connection being dropped, you can use `QSqlDatabase::isOpen()` to test it before you try to execute a query.

Leaving the connection open makes even more sense if you're using prepared queries (`QSqlQuery::prepare`).  The prepared queries will be available as long as the connection is open.

**EDIT**

You can change the inactivity timeout for non-interactive sessions (see [sysvar_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)).  I'm no MySQL expert, but [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488390/mysql-connection-timeout-inactivity).

Comment: I tried to use something along the lines of `if (!db.isOpen()) {db.open();}` but it doesn't work...:( My connection will randomly drop but the if statement wont trigger db.open();, however if I just forget about the if statement and do db.open(); it works..

Comment: How do you know the db connection is being dropped?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: When I click on this button it's supposed to populate my combobox from a table. It works when I click it initially and x amount of times if I don't stop in between. If i dont do anything for over 10 seconds, my combobox doesn't get populated. So now what i do is I run a timer that does `SELECT 1;` every 9 seconds to keep the connection from dropping