# SocketException trigger by MySQL 5.6.22 using Java-5.0.8 connector

Tags: java, mysql, socketexception, connection-reset

I am using facing a SocketException: connection reset problem after 60sec of idle.

My meaning of idle is that I open a connection but do not do anything exception after 60sec (say 61sec) to person a insert/update/select.

Do I need to change the SQL configuration file or can I change some setting to JDBC in my code during connection. If yes, what should I change?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: update question with stack trace

Comment: stacktrace in another PC, unable to copy and paste

Comment: stacktrace not provided, unable to answer question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the idle time out set too low.

See [mysql connection timeout, inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488390/mysql-connection-timeout-inactivity)

You can adjust the time out or tell the connection to auto-reconnect.